# How to split a stream into multiple streams in sequence

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

Using RxJS 6,

I have a stream of arbitrary data:

```
[in] -> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, ....
```

I want to split it into a fixed number N streams in an alternating order (in this case 3 output streams):

```
[out] -> stream1 -> a, d, g
      -> stream2 -> b, e, h
      -> stream3 -> c, f, i
```

or more simply put:

```
a => stream1
b => stream2
c => stream3
d => stream1
e => stream2
f => stream3
g => stream1
h => stream2
i => stream3
```

Any one know how I can do this?

Comment: So you want to have an Observable emitting other Observables (like with `groupBy` operator) or just three different Observables?

Comment: emmiting to three other fixed observables, an array of them actually, that should be created ahead of time, essentially when the number of them (N) is first decided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `N` and split your stream in two at each iteration using `partition`:

```
import { from, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { partition, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']);

function split(source, n) {
  const streams = [];
  let toSplit = source;
  for (let k = n; k > 0; --k) {
    const [stream, rest] = toSplit.pipe(
      partition((_, i) => i % k === 0)
    );
    streams.push(stream);
    toSplit = rest;
  }
  return streams;
}

const obs = split(source, 3);

const subscribe = merge(
  obs[0].pipe(map(val => `1: ${val}`)),
  obs[1].pipe(map(val => `2: ${val}`)),
  obs[2].pipe(map(val => `3: ${val}`)),
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[See this StackBlitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-split-stream)

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling it would be something like this, just didnt know you could get the index in partitions callback.  I assume this is the only reasonable way to achieve this?

Comment: @user2765977, you are welcome. This is the most straightforward way to do it I think.